# Drops to BusyBox, but can continue upon exiting

Tags: 11.10, boot, grub2

So I just installed 11.10 on my Dell Precision T5500 from the live cd.  The live cd worked fine, but when I attempt to boot from hard drive I end up at the BusyBox prompt.  However, if I simply type "exit" and Enter it continues booting and I get the Ubuntu graphical login screen.  How do I fix things so I don't stop at the BusyBox prompt?

I found an interesting similar problem at http://samiux.wordpress.com/2008/12/16/howto-avoid-to-drop-to-busybox-in-ubuntu-810/, but can't exactly implement the solution since the /boot/grub/menu.lst file doesn't appear to exist in 11.10.

Any ideas?  It would be nice to be able to reboot my system remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the solution you found by editing `/etc/default/grub` instead; edit the line labelled `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and run `sudo update-grub` to make the changes take effect.

You should end up with something like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash bootdelay=90"
```

This has the same effect as editing `menu.lst` (actually, it's now called `grub.cfg`) but in a way that the Ubuntu packages understand, so when a kernel or grub gets updated, the changes will persist. You generally don't want to be editing the grub config manually.

Comment: It works!  But the option I had to use was "rootdelay", not "bootdelay" as in the blog I came across.  Thank you, Caesium!