# Cryptsetup: waiting for encrypted source device

Tags: boot, encryption

I just updated my bios as tech support told me to. Now when I boot up my laptop it says “ Cryptsetup: waiting for encrypted source device” where I am supposed to enter my pass phrase.

The screen then goes black and now says

```
[    0.255494] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter ‘help’ for a list of built-in commands. 
(initramfs)
```

I don’t know anything about computers. Would really appreciate if someone could help.

More info, not dual boot with windows. I installed the BIOS update with EZ Flash, the bios update file was on a USB.

I haven’t changed any settings, I simply followed the tutorial that ASUS support have uploaded on their YouTube https://youtu.be/Em7SRaG3L_0

Comment: Please add some more information. Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is this a dual-boot with Windows? How did you install the BIOS update, via Ubuntu or Windows, or some other way? What were the exact steps? Did you change anything in the EFI System Partition (ESP) or in the BIOS settings?

Comment: See the answer to [Upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04 and grub drops to BusyBox prompt without error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186407/upgraded-from-10-04-to-12-04-and-grub-drops-to-busybox-prompt-without-error) and see if it helps.

Comment: Go into the BIOS settings and check that the correct boot device is selected. If you are not sure, add the list of boot devices listed in the BIOS in your question.

Comment: Boot from the Ubuntu installation USB using **Try Ubuntu** option. Open gparted. Make sure the internal drive is selected on top right corner. Take a screenshot of the gparted window. Upload the screenshot in imagur.com and add a link in your question.